# Loop Through Visible Data Only With Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked around and found similar items but I just can't seem to put them to use. I have quite a simple code. The problem is simply checking if a row is hidden takes like 30 minutes to process as I'm using sometimes more than 500,000 rows.

After filtering down the data to about 100 I'd like to only be using this data so that I'm only computing 100 and not checking the other 499,900. Only what's on the screen. It's not working anymore as I'm still playing around with it but, here's my code:

```
Sub HideRows()
    i = 1

    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(Sheets(Wss).Range("H:H").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = 1 And Cells(i, 8).Value = 1 And Cells(i + 1, 8).Row = Cells(i, 8).Row + 1 Then
            Cells(i + 1, 8).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(i + 1, 8).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: `xlCellTypeVisible` doesn't mean "what's currently on my screen" it means "anything on the sheet that isn't hidden".

Comment: To have "what's currently on my screen" you want to do  `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).VisibleRange` or `ActiveWindow.VisibleRange`

Comment: What's that `And Cells(i + 1, 8).Row = Cells(i, 8).Row + 1`? Isn't that always true?

Comment: `cl.Row` is the relevant row in the loop, but you cannot necessarily add one to that and get the next *visible* row.  It would help to explain in words what your code needs to do.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the data is first filtered and then ran thru this macro. Flags are not allowed to appear immediately after each other which is why it's written this way.

Comment: @JerodMclean Well bring your car to the repair shop and tell them "it's not working". The won't be able to help you unless you tell them **what** is not working, or what it does vs. what you expect it to do. There is just no possibility to help you if you don't tell what's wrong. • I posted that link so you can see what's wrong with your post and you can improve it by [edit]ing (reading [ask] might help too). A question without a question in it is just a bad one.

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry. Let me try again. So I have half a million points and when large fluctuations occur this will set a flag "1". These ones are then filtered from 500k to, say, 1000. These flags are then filtered down once again with this macro. This macro is hiding any rows with 1's directly after each other (hence, the same fluctuation simply over a larger time). And I only need when the fluctuation is starting.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've added comments replied to others if you care to help. The only thing I can add is I need to calculate only what's on the screen (and the 500 visible lines under) without calculating anything hidden. Not even checking it. I don't know how to code this or use ranges and I've been trying for hours. I don't use VB ever. I get a run time error but I know it's more wrong than that. I didn't know we were allowed to edit btw lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub HideRows()
    Const ROW_START As Long = 1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, a As Range, rngVis As Range, bHide As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = ws.Range(ws.Cells(ROW_START, "H"), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no visible rows
    
    For Each a In rngVis.Areas 'loop range areas
        bHide = False          'reset flag
        For Each c In a.Rows   'loop rows in area
             If c.Value = 1 Then
                If bHide Then c.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'second or later "1"  - hide row
                bHide = True   'set flag for later rows
             Else
                bHide = False  'unset flag for later rows
             End If
        Next c
    Next a
End Sub
```